# How to give admin option of signing out online users

Tags: c#, silverlight, asp.net-membership, wcf-ria-services

In an asp.net membership role based security system, Is there a way to force sign out an online user?

Imagine user is on line and have a session on client application like silverlight (WCF RIA). Now if admin goes and edit a data specific to user and user update the same data after admin. All changes applied by the admin will be lost. Is there a way for admin to force log out the user before changing his/her data?

Answer (score 0):

mmm not tried, but what's about putting an HttpInspector and clear the cookie that identify the session ?